# How do you catch a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException correctly?

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I am working on a web application, and at a point where I submit forms that are unique to the user, a

```
 MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException Duplicate entry -'username' 
for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I am well aware of why this is being thrown, because I am attempting to enter a duplicate entry into the database with the same primary key. I would appreciate no comments on this, as it might be a redundant.

What I am really asking is how should I handle this. I have attempted to catch this exception, but apparently my lack of experience has caught up to me.

I would appreciate your help with it.

Is there a better method for checking for duplicate entries in a database?

For example, should I do what I do when checking for duplicate members, and just do a check to the database for a matching username and password?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if it's possible avoid throwing Exceptions since they are a heavy mechanism for controlling program workflow. You should only use them to trace bugs and irregular activities/situations.  All that means that if you catch an exception, the only thing you can do is log some more, wrap the exception in another exception and eventually triggering some fall-back program logic.

Don't expect to catch exceptions and just check for correct user name. I suppose you will be doing this check a lot if you are developing some sort of registration form ... there are a few popular words for common users and if you implement it with exceptions, you will catch it pretty often...

Unfortunately, if your database is very large, the primary keys are many and complex objects , than you can't afford to keep some of the elements in memory to perform this check for duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, especially in this scenario it is better to check whether another user exists with the same username *before* trying to insert the user.

Comment: Assuming that you don't have all the user names in memory, how is it better to check if the id exists before trying to insert the record?  You are going to incur a database look-up for each insertion instead of an occasional exception.

Comment: you normally have an index on that field, so lookup is pretty fast.

Comment: But it still requires a round trip on the network.  That's orders of magnitude slower than an Exception.

Comment: if you measure that it's a serious problem (e.g. 10 ms vs 500 ms), then of course, catch the exception. If the absolute value of the request, and the frequency of usage of the piece of code does not mean it's a problem, then either works

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem , try handling the exception with the `catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException sql)` .
But **don't forget there are 2 types ofMySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException** one for JDBC and one for JDBC4 . 
So i recommend to catch both in two separate try catch loops.